# My input fields are not being captured when placed in a toolbar

Tags: javascript, forms, input, toolbar

I'm building a job search bookmarklet. It will take your keyword and location and open multiple search tabs.

For some reason, the first link for searching via Dice.com is not capturing the input fields and fails to work when all is put into the toolbar.

The final version will open each subsequent tab with a 1010ms delay for each site selected.

I have most of the code finished and it looks fine, but when I click on the hyperlink for Dice, nothing happens.

**Drag & Drop Bookmarklet:**

https://codepen.io/bookmarklets/pen/xeqJZb#

The above Codepen opens a button, which is a bookmarklet that you drag into your bookmarks bar. The bookmarklet code is visible in the Codepen HTML window. The Codepen CSS can be ignored as it only pertains to this convenient button, not the actual bookmarlet.

```
<div style="float:left"><table><tr><td style="border-right-style:solid;text-align:right"><b>Job Searcher</b> &nbsp;<br><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)"; checked><label for="all" id="all" name="all"> All </label><input type="submit"> &nbsp;</td><td style="border-right-style:solid;border-right-color:#555;border-right-width:1px"><form><input type="text" placeholder="Enter&nbsp;Job&nbsp;Title" name="jobTitle" id="jobTitle" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;<br><input type="text" placeholder="Enter&nbsp;Location" name="jobLocation" id="jobLocation" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>  &nbsp; <img src="https://assets.dice.com/techpro/img/favicons/favicon-32x32.png" height="16" /> &nbsp;<input type="checkbox" checked name="dice" id="dice"> <a onClick="goDice()"; href="#"> Dice</a></td></tr></table>
```

```
function goDice(){
    var role = document.getElementById('jobTitle').value;
    var b = document.getElementById('site').value;
    var goToDice='https://www.dice.com/jobs?q='+ role +'&l=' + b;
    goToDice = goToDice.replace(/[ ]/g,'+');
    goToDice = goToDice.replace(/,/g,'%2C');
    window.open(goToDice);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your id's aren't matching up between HTML and JS.

In JS, you have:

```
var role = document.getElementById('jobTitle').value;
var b = document.getElementById('site').value;
```

Meanwhile, in HTML you have:

```
id="jobTitle/"
id="jobLocation"
```

Fixing these, the Dice link does open, and in a new window.

On a side note, it's better to never use a `/` in a name.

Comment: Thanks! You are the boss! I can't believe I didn't see such stupid mistakes! I need a new JS editor. :)